# Is it possible to Command-click a symbol into a new tab in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, hotkeys

I am searching for a keyboard shortcut that allows me to combine 'Cmd-t' (open new tab) and 'Cmd-click on a symbol' (jump to definition). I want to be able to open the symbol definition in a new tab, much like Cmd-click (Ctrl-click on Windows) opens a link in a new tab when using a web browser.

I tried some different combinations but have given up after Cmd-option-Shift-click crashed Xcode!

I'm currently using Xcode 4.6.1.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

1. Go to XCode->Preferences,
2. Select Navigation tab,
3. Change "Double Click Navigation" to "Uses Separate Tab"

Now command-double-click the symbol to open in new tab.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, this works perfect in Xcode 5.1.1.

Comment: I would set "Optional navigation" to "Uses Separate Tab" and then use Option + Click

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way I found is,

```
Cmd+T new tab.
Then Cmd+Click on the symbol.
```

I think Xcode should have, `Cmd+Shift+Click` to open the function/class in new tab. OR `Alt+Cmd+O` or something like this :)

`UPDATE:` It was an old trick. Now you can use @Leigh answer. `Cmd + double click + (set preferences to open double click navigation in new tab)`

Answer (score 3):

Funny you mentioned `⌘⌥⇧-click` because you can open the definition in a new tab with that. Unfortunately you also need to click on the right `+` sign that appears in the window navigator after you do this, so it's somehow a 2 step action. I don't think there's another way to do it. Apple calls it "Jump to Definition In...", since you can choose where to open it. Also, if you're a keyboard person `^⌘⌥⇧J`

Comment: yep works, but for some reason that window navigator stresses my machine! If you do get it to come up then you can `↑, →, Enter` to open that tab without leaving your keyboard :) Also, `^⌘⌥⇧J` appears to work from the keyboard only after highlighting the whole symbol (`⌘⌥→`).

Answer (score 2):

Selecting in the editor, the one step method for this is to `⌥⌘ click`.  With `⌥⌘`, the cursor will change to a pointing finger. Clicking opens that symbol in a new tab.

Selecting in the project navigator, use `⌘ double click`.